# How can I update chart with state change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

When I am listing the new data it updates but then the chart only updates the first time.  I don't have access inside the Line component so I can't do componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) for that one.  How can I update the chart with each new state change?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {Line} from 'react-chartjs-2';

class Chart extends Component {

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    debugger
    this.setState({ data: nextProps.info });
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    }

  }


  render() {

    let chart = {
        chartData:{
        labels: this.state.data,
        datasets:[
          {
            label: 'Weight',
            data: this.state.data,
            backgroundColor:[
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)',
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }

    return (
      <div className="chart" style={{height: 200 + "px", width: 100 + "%"}}>
        <Line
            data={chart.chartData}
            width={100}
            height={50}
            options={{
              maintainAspectRatio: false
            }}
        />
        <ul>
        {this.state.data.map(val=> <li>{val}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you planning on changing `data` inside that component? If not, you don't need to use `state` at all and you can just use `this.props.info` directly in `render()` .